# Create external identifier from python function odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I want to create external identifiers for model 'res.product' from another model.. I tried the following code, but not generated exact as when we export data

```
collections=self.env['res.product'].search([('categ','=','nuts')])
        if collections:


            for col in collections:
               

                postfix = 0
                name = '%s_%s' % (col._table, col.id)
                print("name",name)
                ir_model_data = self.sudo().env['ir.model.data']
                while ir_model_data.search([('module', '=', '__export__'), ('name', '=', name)]):
                    postfix += 1
                    name = '%s_%s_%s' % (col._table, 21, postfix)
                ir_model_data.create({
                    'model': 'res.product',
                    'res_id': col.id,
                    'module': '__export__',
                    'name': name,
                })
```

Comment: Please add more details to the question, it is hard to understand exactly what you're asking about without interpreting the code itself

Comment: Atleast add a good set of examples, what you would expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If `ir.model.data` already exists for that one record, you should update it instead of creating a duplicate.

```
for col in self.env['res.product'].search([('categ','=','nuts')]):
  ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data'].sudo().search([
    ('model', '=', 'res.product'),
    ('res_id', '=', col.id)
  ])

  if ir_model_data:
    ir_model_data.write({"name": "UNIVOQUE_EXTERNAL_ID"})
  else:
    self.env['ir.model.data'].create({
      "model": "res.product",
      "res_id": res.id,
      "module": "__import__",
      "name": "UNIVOQUE_EXTERNAL_ID"
    })
```

You should consider adding this logic in `create` function of `res.product` model. This way it won't be massive.

Otherwise, if it is a one time operation, consider directly executing an SQL query in your database.

`UPDATE ir_model_data SET name = 'UNIVOQUE_NAME' WHERE model = 'res.product' AND id = 123;`

Note that `module` attribute in `ir_model_data` indicates if record has been imported, exported or initiated via module `data`.
Consider using your module name as `module` or, depending on your needs, `__import__` or `__export__` tags.